# Can multiple people jointly sacrifice one animal for Eid ul-Adha?

Tags: sacrifice, eid-ul-adha

I have a questions regarding [qurbani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qurbani).

In our countries (like India, Pakistan, Bangladesh) people attribute 7 people to a sacrifice of a buffalo or camel, and 1 person to a goat/sheep.  Is there any reason behind that or not?  Is there any hadith about that?

I don't have any idea whether Saudi or any Middle East countries use any names or not.

Answer (score 4):

That's a well-known rule for sacrifice: a buffalo or a camel can be shared by seven people.

> Sahih Muslim | The Book of Pilgrimage
>
> **Chapter: It is permissible to share in the sacrifice, and a camel or a cow is sufficient for seven people**
>
> Jabir b. 'Abdullah (Allah be pleased with him) reported:
>
> In the year of Hudaibiya (6 H ), we, along with Allah's Messenger (way peace be upon him), sacrificed a camel for seven persons and a cow for seven persons.
>
> http://sunnah.com/muslim/15/389